# How memory leak will occur in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, memory-management

I am new to  ios development and i want to learn how memory leak will occur in `swift` or in `Objective-C`, can any one explain with small example?

Thanks

Comment: Retain Cycle, playing with low API (like `CGPath`, etc. where you should do call yourself the CGReleaseStuff), etc.

Comment: `retain cycles` - multiple objects holding strong references to each other: `A` references `B` while `B` references `A`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Small example:

```
class A {
    var b: B!

    deinit {
        print("deinit of A")
    }
}

class B {
    var a: A!

    deinit {
        print("deinit of B")
    }
}

do {
    let a = A()
    let b = B()
    a.b = b
    b.a = a
}
```

If you run this code (maybe in Playground), it will print nothing. It means that `deinit` never called for both objects and they just leaked.

But if you declare one of the properties as `weak`:

```
class A {
    weak var b: B!

    deinit {
        print("deinit of A")
    }
}
```

Then `deinit` will be called and you'll see messages in console.

**Edit: add example with closures**

Consider this example:

```
class C {
    var f: (Void -> Void)!

    deinit {
        print("deinit for C")
    }
}

do {
    let c = C()
    c.f = {
        print(c)
    }
}
```

`c` captures `f`, `f` captures `c`. So we got memory leak.

To deal with leaks in closures, you have 2 options – declare that captured object is `weak` or `unowned`. Like this:

```
do {
    let c = C()
    c.f = { [weak c] in
        print(c)
    }
}
```

Basically, you would use `weak` if it's possible for object to get out of existence and become `nil` when closure is called; but if you are sure object will still exist at this time, use `unowned` instead.

After I declare `c` as `weak` inside a closure, "deinit for C" is printed – means that everything deallocated successfully.

**What this all means for you, the developer?**

Almost all the time you don't have to worry about the memory management. It's done for you, automatically. Objects just exist when you need them and vanish when you don't. But there are 2 very common cases when you need to be careful and think about memory.

1. Delegation. It's common pattern in Cocoa and it could create retain cycles if done wrong. Always declare your delegate as `weak` unless you have a good reason not to.
2. Closures. Closure capture references for objects in surrounding scope and does it automatically, without notice. When implementing closure, chech if it will create retain cycle. If yes, declare problem variables as `weak` or `unowned`.

For further info I suggest you read official Apple Swift book which can be found in iBooks or [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-ID0) as a website.

Comment: Thanks for your example. need some info on this. is in this one case only memory will leak? or any other list of conditions may memory leak occurs

Comment: Closure also can cause memory leaks. I'll edit my answer to give more information.

Comment: why do you need the `do` block in your first example?